# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec() Não executa comandos com espaço

Tags: java, socket, runtime

Tenho um socket cliente e um servidor, o cliente envia um comando para o servidor executar, mas quando o comando possui espaços, o servidor gera uma exceção: 
java.io.IOException: invalid null character in command

Código do Servidor:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class UDPServidor{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        DatagramSocket servidorSocket = new DatagramSocket(9876);
        byte[] dadosRecebidos = new byte[1024];
        byte[] dadosEnviados = new byte[1024];
        while(true){
            dadosRecebidos = new byte[1024];
            dadosEnviados = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket pacoteRecebido = new DatagramPacket(dadosRecebidos,dadosRecebidos.length);

            servidorSocket.receive(pacoteRecebido);
            String sentence = null;
            sentence = new String(pacoteRecebido.getData());

            InetAddress enderecoIP = pacoteRecebido.getAddress();
            int porta = pacoteRecebido.getPort();
            System.out.println("Comando Recebido = " + sentence);
            Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {
                Process p = run.exec(sentence);
                String line = null;     

                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                input.close();

                System.out.println("\n##Processo Finalizado.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String sentenceCapturada = sentence.toUpperCase();

            dadosEnviados = sentenceCapturada.getBytes();

            DatagramPacket pacoteEnviado = new DatagramPacket(dadosEnviados,dadosEnviados.length,enderecoIP,porta);
            servidorSocket.send(pacoteEnviado);
        }

}
}
```

Código do Cliente:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;

    public class UDPCliente{
         public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         BufferedReader cadeidaUsuario = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         DatagramSocket clienteSocket = new DatagramSocket();

         InetAddress enderecoIP = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
         byte[] enviaDados = new byte[1024];
         byte[] recebeDados = new byte[1024];

         String sentence = cadeidaUsuario.readLine();
         enviaDados = sentence.getBytes();

         DatagramPacket enviaPacote = new DatagramPacket(enviaDados,enviaDados.length,enderecoIP,9876);
         clienteSocket.send(enviaPacote);

        DatagramPacket recebePacote = new DatagramPacket(recebeDados,recebeDados.length);
        clienteSocket.receive(recebePacote);
        String sentenceModificada = new  String(recebePacote.getData());
        System.out.println("Código recebido com sucesso: "+ sentenceModificada);
        clienteSocket.close();

        }
 }
```

Comment: Já tentou imprimir a instrução no servidor antes de rodar? Se sim, a saída fica correta? Com espaços ou com caracteres "estranhos" no lugar dos espaços?

Comment: Sim, eu imprimo o comando no servidor e a saída está correta, igualzinho a entrada

Comment: Esse "comando" é pra rodar no Windows? Tem como mostrar um dos comandos que dá erro?

Comment: Não, estou rodando no Linux Ubuntu. Ele dá erro quando o comando é "mkdir teste" ou quanquer outro comando que tenha espaço, mas quando eu sou um "ls" ou "eject" ele funciona normalmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente 'Limpar' a `String` antes de executar o comando:

```
  String sentence = null;
  sentence = new String(pacoteRecebido.getData()).trim();
```

Acontece que ao enviar sua `String`,  ele irá completar os `1024 bytes` restantes com caracteres vazios!

Comment: Deu certo! Era isso mesmo, muito obrigada pela ajuda!!!